# Box2D SetAsOrientedBox

Tags: box2d

The command "SetAsOrientedBox" in Box2D doesn't work anymore. I couldn't find out the new command for it. Can someone tell me the new command?

Old example:
boxDef.SetAsOrientedBox(0.4, 0.1, new b2Vec(0.1, 0.1), 0.3);

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the as3 port SetAsOrientedBox should work. If you are using the Alchemy port the SetAsBox method takes the size and the position of the body def.